# Starting hyperledger explorer fails

Tags: hyperledger-explorer

I have installed all prerequisites for setting up the hyperledger Explorer but when I start it, I got the following error in log file:

```
postgres://hppoc:password@127.0.0.1/fabricexplorer
fs.js:675
return binding.read(fd, buffer, offset, length, position);
             ^

Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
at Object.fs.readSync (fs.js:675:18)
at tryReadSync (fs.js:540:20)
at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:583:19)
at configuration.getPeersByOrg.forEach.key (/home/ubuntu/blockchain-explorer/app/FabricClientProxy.js:164:20)
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at FabricClientProxy.setupPeers (/home/ubuntu/blockchain-explorer/app/FabricClientProxy.js:161:36)
at configuration.getOrgs.forEach.key (/home/ubuntu/blockchain-explorer/app/FabricClientProxy.js:155:10)
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at FabricClientProxy.createDefault (/home/ubuntu/blockchain-explorer/app/FabricClientProxy.js:137:27)
at new FabricClientProxy (/home/ubuntu/blockchain-explorer/app/FabricClientProxy.js:32:8)
```

Comment: This is going to be hard to help you with, as it is probably environmental (or some sort of bug that is best researched elsewhere). EISDIR means that something is trying to do something that can only be done on non-directory. Review your setup and configuration. What research have you done to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error suggests, you have specified a directory instead of a file on which read operation is happening, I think somewhere in the config.json file you have given an incorrect path. Please check or post the config.json file so the issue can be identified.

Comment: Yes You are right i have mentioned a directory istead of mentioning file